# What is the difference between solo and alone?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, translation

I was searching the meanings of these two words:

> *alone* and *solo*

And, *(according to the [source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/alone)),* both shares the same meaning:

> *alone; without other ​people.*

Both words sounds *for me* interchangeable in usage "speaking, writing, etc".

As the title says: **what is the difference between solo and alone?** and **there are rules for the usage of each one of them?**

---

*The answer should show references and example usages for learning purposes (i.e: for get a better understanting about its usage).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have similar meanings, but they are not used in the same semantic contexts, and they cannot both be used in all the same syntactic contexts.

- ***solo*** is mostly used to speak only of actions; ***alone*** is also used to speak of anything physically isolated.
- ***solo*** can be used as a noun ("a drum solo") or verb ("Rich soloed the third chorus"); ***alone*** cannot.
- ***solo*** is used as an attributive adjective before its head noun ("a solo performance"); ***alone*** is used as an attributive adjective after its head ("John alone was successful").
- ***alone*** can be used as an adjectival predicate complement ("Amy was now alone"); ***solo*** is very rarely used this way.

It is really only as adverbs that their uses overlap: "John acted alone", "John acted solo".

Answer (score 0):

Both mean a **singular** person, by themselves.

**Solo** is usually used when doing something *active*: **solo effort**, **singing a solo**, **solo competition**.
**Alone** is usually used when doing something *inactive*: **sat alone**, **went alone**.

But the lines can often blurred with the two usages and meanings.

One would say **solo effort** not **alone effort**, or **all alone** but not **all solo** (unless it was a collection of soloists).

**Solo** has the feeling of being singular in effort (with a crowd watching and/or involved), whereas **alone** has the feeling of being solitary (with no one watching):

> The concert hall was filled for the Yo-Yo Ma's **solo** recital.
>   The farmer sat in his field **alone** as the storm gathered.